# Application not using Lookaside List

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

Using Dev-C++ 4.9.2. I'm allocating a new heap via HeapCreate, then doing two HeapAlloc's (to allocate two heap segments), then free'ing the second heap segment via HeapFree... This is all on Windows XP SP3. When I'm doing free'ing the second heap segment, instead of going to the LookAside List (LAL) like it should, it instead merges the second segment with unallocated memory in the heap. So I just end up with one heap segment still alloc'ed and no second segment at all. When I should end up with one heap segment alloc'ed and the second segment on the LAL.

Any ideas?

I'm using some basic heap overflow code (Trying to understand how Heap Overflows work in order to code safer) from http://www.net-ninja.net/article/2011/Sep/03/heap-overflows-for-humans-102/ and I've compiled it using Dev-C++ 4.9.2.

Comment: Include the relevant code, and you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: May I suggest upgrading to http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/?source=directory as a first step? It has a much more capable debugger, compiler, etc.